# Can't install wine mono on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, windows, wine

I have installed wine on ubuntu and now I want to install wine mono with the following comand

```
wine msiexec /i Downloads/wine-mono-4.7.1.msi
```

But the installer doesn't start and I get the following error:

```
0038:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0038:fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for +01, bias -60, std (d/m/y): 27/10/2018, dlt (d/m/y): 25/03/2018
0038:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
0038:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
```

Thenks in advance for your help.

Comment: there's wine thread about exactly that
https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=397
sounds like a regression they should fix

Comment: ok thank you, it worked by installing mono-complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 18.04 (Bionic) repositories there's currently [a package available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mono-complete) for installation.

Before you can install it you need to [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and then simply issue the command `sudo apt install mono-complete`

Comment: I still get the error message: 0009:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed

Comment: @derchambers Welcome to AskUbuntu! It sounds like you have a different problem than the one resolved here. You may wish to [ask a new question.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) Cheers!